# Authenticate WiFi with certificate instead of password

Tags: wireless-networking, tls, radius

Is it possible (read done without a massive amount of work) to set up a wireless network that checks for a certificate instead of asking for a password?

To be clear: I would like to download a certificate to multiple device and then have those devices connect to my wifi without being promoted for a password.

Thanks

Comment: I just read RADIUS servers use certs. http://freeradius.org/ is one. Depending on how much work is "massive amount", you may want to check it out.

Comment: I looked into that. Do you know if you can authenticate solely with a cert or is it just used to secure the client-server connection?